# Is it possible to run IoT-Agent for Ultralight 2.0 without MondoDB link (with memory type of data hold)?

Tags: fiware

During configuring IoT-Agent for Ultralight 2.0 there is a possibility to set docker variable *IOTA_REGISTRY_TYPE*- Whether to hold IoT device info in memory or in a database (mongodb by default). [Documentation that I'm referencing.](https://fiware-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/iot-agent/index.html)

Firstly I would like to have it set for memory and what would it imply? 
Could the data be preserved only in some allocated part of memory within docker env.? Could I omit further variables within configuration file, like *IOTA_MONGO_HOST* (The hostname of mongoDB - used for holding device information).

Architecture for my system has raspberry pi running IoT Agent and VM running Orion Context Broker and MongoDB. Both are reachable because they see each other in LAN. Is it necessary for MongoDB to be the same database for IoT Agent and Orion Context Broker if they are linked?

Is it possible to run IoT Agent with memory only type of device information persistence (instead of database type)? Will it have any effect on whole infrastructure running besides of obvious lack of device data holding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Firstly I would like to have it set for memory and what would it imply?

There would be no need for a MongoDB database attached to the IoT Agent, there would be no persistence of provisioned devices in the event of disaster recovery.

> Could the data be preserved only in some allocated part of memory within docker env.?

No

> Could I omit further variables within configuration file, like IOTA_MONGO_HOST (The hostname of mongoDB - used for holding device information).

The [Docker Env parameters](https://iotagent-node-lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installationguide/index.html#configuration-using-environment-variables) are merely overrides to the values found in the `config.js` within the Enabler itself, so all of the `ENV` variables can be omitted if you are using defaults.

> Is it necessary for MongoDB to be the same database for IoT Agent and Orion
>   Context Broker if they are linked?

The IoT Agent and Orion can run entirely separately and usually would use separate MongoDB instances. At least this would be the case in a properly architected production environment.

The **Step-by-Step Tutorials** are lumping everything together on one Docker engine for simplicity. A proper architecture has been sacrificed to keep the narrative focused on the learning goals. You don't need two Mongo-DB instances to handle less than 20 dummy devices.

When deploying to a production environment, try looking at the SmartSDK Recipes
in order to scale up to a proper architecture:

see: https://smartsdk.github.io/smartsdk-recipes/

> Is it possible to run IoT Agent with memory only type of device information
>   persistence (instead of database type)? Will it have any effect on whole
>   infrastructure running besides of obvious lack of device data holding?

I haven't checked this, but there may be a slight difference in performance since memory access should be slightly faster. The pay-off is that you will lose the provisioned state of all devices if failure occurs. If you need to invest in disaster recovery then Mongo-DB is the way to go, and periodically back-up your database so you can always return to *last-known-good*